# HTML form with advanced editing for user (HTML edit)

Tags: html, forms

I have a text_area on my form but by default they only accept text, I was trying to enable something like advanced editing that would allow users to put tags, bolds, etc, quickly.

This feature is available on this exact stackoverflow area input where im typing right now and is very common on forums, etc. Is there any quick way to enable this on my side?

Comment: it's called `wysywyg` just so you know. Google it and you'll get fantastic results

Answer (score 1):

Well if you create your own then it will take much time to built a just like one.

and if you want a quick solution then search for editors like **ck-editor** and there are lot more editors just like that

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't. HTML  elements can only contain plain text.

You will need to use a Javascript rich text editor component such as TinyMCE or CKEditor.